# Weights of edges as labels

Tags: python, networkx, graphviz

Given a graph like the one below:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import graphviz

df = pd.DataFrame({'id_emp' : [13524791000109, 12053850000137, 4707821000113, 4707821000114, 1],
               'name_emp': ['Cristiano', 'Gaúcho', 'Fenômeno','Angelin', 'Souza'],
               'name_dep': ['Ronaldo','Iker', 'Adriano', 'Adriano', 'Bruno'],
               'Team': ['Real','Real', 'Flamengo','Flamengo','Boa'],
               'weight1': [3,5,7,8,12],
               'weight2': [4,6,7,9,14]})

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_nodes_from(df['id_emp'], bipartite = 0)
emp = [v for v in G.nodes if G.nodes[v]['bipartite'] == 0]

G.add_nodes_from(df['name_dep'], bipartite = 1)
dep = [v for v in G.nodes if G.nodes[v]['bipartite'] == 1]

G.add_weighted_edges_from(df[['name_dep', 'id_emp', 'weight1']].values)
G.add_weighted_edges_from(df[['id_emp', 'name_dep', 'weight2']].values)
```

I'm using Graphviz to draw it:

```
import graphviz

d = graphviz.Digraph()

for n in dep:
   d.node(str(n), color="#bfbf7f")

for n in emp:
    d.node(str(n), color="red")

for e in G.edges:
    d.edge(str(e[0]), str(e[1]))
    d.edge(str(e[1]), str(e[0]))

d.attr(size='10')

d.engine='circo'
d
```

output:[image]

However, it is important that the weight of the edges is informed. Using `G.edges.data('weight')`, I can see the value of the weight of each edge in the graph G, how can I put the values ​​of the weights as labels of the edges in graphviz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print(G.edges(data=True))
# [(13524791000109, 'Ronaldo', {'weight': 4}), (12053850000137, 'Iker', {'weight': 6}), (4707821000113, 'Adriano', {'weight': 7}), (4707821000114, 'Adriano', {'weight': 9}), (1, 'Bruno', {'weight': 14})]
```

You can use the `label` keyword argument.

```
for (u,v) in G.edges:
    d.edge(str(u), str(v), label=str(G[u][v]['weight']))
    d.edge(str(v), str(u), label=str(G[v][u]['weight']))
```

which outputs:

```
d.render()
```

[image]

Comment: How would I do this in a nx.Multidigraph(). I'm trying and the output is:
too many values to unpack (expected 2)